# How to overlay an osmar shape over a ggmap with R?

Tags: r, google-maps, osmar

I am having trouble overlaying an osmar shape over a ggmap with R.

I get the osmar object (in this case it is Lake Park in Milwaukee, WI):

```
lp<-get_osm(relation(6044259), full=T)
```

I convert it to a shape:

```
lpp<-as_sp(lp, "lines")
```

This looks fine and I see the outline of the park:

```
[plot(lpp)][1]
```

I then try to overlay this over a map:

```
area.points <- fortify(lpp)
mapImage <- get_map(location = c(lon = -87.89, lat = 43.05),  color = "color",           source = "google",  zoom = 13)
ggmap(mapImage) + geom_path(aes(x=long,y=lat), data=area.points, color=colors[9], alpha=0.5)+labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude")
```

When I plot the map and the area overlay of the park it is not cleanly plotting the park outline but seems to also be plotting a line between each point.

[ggmap output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeH7A.png)

Answer (score 1):

adding `group=group` in the aes section of geom_path solved the problem:

```
ggmap(mapImage) + geom_path(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group), data=area.points, 
                            color=colors[9], alpha=0.5)+
                  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude")
```